# net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My problem is that my project (a simple hotel management project) is throwing a "net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000" when I try to run it for the first time. I dont know about this "00000000"?? I am using hibernate and spring in my project

Answer (score 1):

ehCache stores cache values to the disk and cache keys to memory.
Cache keys from memory map to value objects on the disk. Thus Ehcache is claiming a serialized value on the disk and yet none is found there causing this issue. This indeed can happen if disk store files are written on a shared disk by multiple processes.

The solution is to run other applications under other accounts